# Passing Parameters for SwitchNavigator for react-navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to set up an authentication flow in react-navigation as described [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow.html). I'm able to navigate between the screens but cannot pass in the props.

In the log-in screen, we navigate to the Application as follows:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('App', {user: "hello"});
```

And then in the application, we try to access the `user` value as follows:

```
const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;
const userId = params ? params.user : null;
```

Printing out `params` gives the following:

```
{routeName:"Home",key:"id-1524078856706-13"}
```

I've made a simple [Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@briank621/passing-props-in-switchnavigator) to demonstrate the problem. It seems as if the above approach only works for a StackNavigator? Must I revert to a StackNavigator?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must pass the params to the `routeName` that has been registered in the app's router rather than passing it to the app's router as mentioned [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop.html#navigate-link-to-other-screens)

> *params - Params to merge into the destination route*

Right now you're passing the `params` to the `StackRouter **App**`

To fix this you can simply call

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('Home', {user: "hello"});
```

Comment: great, it is working perfectly. is there any effect my application ?